An unknown setting with identifier [8] and value [0] was ignored
I have this error in my Tomcat log file:
[2024-09-26 13:46:12] [warning] Connection [8], An unknown setting with identifier [8] and value [0] was ignored
[2024-09-26 13:46:14] [warning] Connection [9], An unknown setting with identifier [8] and value [0] was ignored

And I tried everything in my configuration files but I can't find the cause
